# iCloud + Core Data: First import and user's feeling of loss of data

Tags: ios, core-data, architecture, synchronization, icloud

I've implemented an iPhone application that has around 50k users. Switching from iOS7 to iOS8 a lot of these users have experienced a terrible feeling when they thought that they data get lost.

I've implemented the first-import behaviour that I thought was the one suggested by Apple

**1)** Users launch the App

**2)** iCloud, **automatically**, starts synching data previously stored on iCloud

**3)** *At some point* user get notified that data from iCloud is ready thanks to `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted`

The problem is with **3) At some point**:
Users that have to sync a lot of data need minutes to get the synch completed and in the meanwhile they think that their data is lost.

I really don't know how to let my users know that they have to wait to see their data synched, because **I don't know when this operation starts**.

**I'm thinking about a possible solution:**

During the first launch of the App, asking to the user if he wants to use iCloud. If he chooses to use it, building the database with iCloud options, so I know exactly that the synch is starting here (I suppose...) 
I'm really not sure about how to implement this behaviour since I've always seen Core Data settings into the `AppDelegate` but to achieve this behaviour I suppose I need to move all the CoreData settings in a Controller.

What do you think about this solution? how are you working around this problem in you Apps?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is right, at least it is that what we do. But leave it in the appDelegate.

Differentiate between with iCloud and without iCloud when doing the "addPersistentStoreWithType". If you do it with iCloud options, it will directly start to build the local store which is a kind of a placeholder ( I'm sure you know that, but just to make my thoughts clear). As soon as this is done, the sync starts from iCloud. So this is the starting point I understood you were looking for.

You can watch that process using the notifications by NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification and inform you user accordingly triggered by that notification.

If you look at "Reacting to iCloud Events" in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW5 there is a detailed desc.

Comment: The right event to watch is NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification thank you!

Comment: I've unaccepted your answer since the "willChange" event gets called when the data are already download from iCloud :(

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, the event you're describing is part of the account transitions process. An account transition occurs when one of the following four events is triggered:

- Initial import
- the iCloud account used did change
- iCloud is disabled
- your application's data is deleted

During this event, Core Data will post the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` notifications to let you know that an account transition is happening. The transition type we're interested in is `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted`.

For information, I've moved all Core Data related code to my own Manager for simplicity and use it with a singleton design pattern. While setting up the singleton, I register the Manager for all relevant notifications (`NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorWillRemoveStoreNotification`).
I store several informations in my settings (`NSUserDefaults` or anything) like the last iCloud state (enabled, disabled, unknown), if the initial import is done or not, etc.

What I end up doing was having a prompt (`UIAlertController` or anything) to get a confirmation if the user wants to use iCloud or not. I have a `displayICloudDialogAndForce:completion:` method to do that and only do that if my iCloud state setting is unknown or I use the force parameter.

Then, after the user input, I call a `setupCoreDataWithICloud:` method, the *`iCloud`* boolean parameter depending on the user choice. I would then setup my Core Data stack, on the cloud or not according to the *`iCloud`* parameter.
If I'm setting up using iCloud, I would check my settings for the value of an iCloud imported key (boolean). If the value is NO, then I'm presenting a new modal to warn the user about the incoming import that could take some time.

I've registered my manager for different notifications and specially `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification`. In my `storeDidChange:` callback, I'm checking the transition type and if it's `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted`, I'm changing the content of my modal to show the user that the import was successful and removing it a few seconds later, saving in my settings that the initial import is done.

```
- (void)storeDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType transitionType = [notification.userInfo[NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey] integerValue];

    if (transitionType == NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted) {
        [settings setDefaults:@(YES) forKey:kSettingsICloudImportedKey];
        [ICloudModal dismissWithSuccess];

        // ...
    }

    // Do other relevant things...
}
```

Comment: And what do you do at the first launch when NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted is not get called?  You present the modal at the first launch... but if the user hasn't data stored on iCloud the initialImportComplete notification is never called so the modal is never closed

Comment: @MatterGoal a possible way to handle that is to watch the ubiquity container. Do a query, initially. if iCloud documents are present (there is a /coredata folder) then the user has core data stores saved to their iCloud. If there isn't a /coredata folder, there won't be a sync. Just a theory.